# Loop through the rows of single DataTable VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm having trouble trying to iterate a Datatable or even use the Linq class.

I have a table as Such:

```
(String)      (String)        (String)      (String)  (Integer)
Criteria    | description   |  Option   |   Title   | status
------------------------------------------------------------
Criteria 1    Lorem Ipsum      Option 1     Class #     0 
Criteria 1    Lorem Ipsum      Option 1     Class #     0 

Criteria 2    Lorem Ipsum      Option 1     Class #     0 
Criteria 2    Lorem Ipsum      Option 2     Class #     1 
Criteria 2    Lorem Ipsum      Option 3     Class #     0 

Criteria 3    Lorem Ipsum      Option 1     Class #     0 
Criteria 3    Lorem Ipsum      Option 2     Class #     1 
Criteria 3    Lorem Ipsum      Option 2     Class #     0 
Criteria 3    Lorem Ipsum      Option 3     Class #     0
```

This is my CodeBehind

```
--VB.NET--
Dim dt As DataTable = StoredProcedure    

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
  Dim sCriteriaOne As DataRow() = dt.Select("Criteria='Criteria 1'")

  Item.Append("<p>" + CStr(sCritOne.Item("Option")) + "</p>")
Next
```

Currently it won't compile and gives me 'Item' is not a member of DataRow()

What I'm trying to acheive is to be able to Loop through the DataTable and append *that* rows Item if it meets the condition. I had tried using Linq but my understanding on that is limited, though I did read through many other MSDN documents and SO posts on questions similar to this.

Comment: Thats because `sCriteriaOne` is an array of `DataRow` and `Item` is not a member of that object... If you dont want an array remove the `()` and otherwise you will need to iterate the array ... if you dont remove them. Turn option strict on as well.

Comment: You appear to be iterating through the rows, then within each iteration, performing the select - so you're doing the same, or similar, thing twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your loop started just fine but fell apart in the details. I guessed at what you were trying to do but maybe this will be enough to get you started. The `$` before the string is an interpolated string which allows you to put variables in line in your string surrounded by `{ }`. If you have an older version of vb you will have to use the old method `String.Format`. To check how the data is being updated check the immediate window after you end the program. That is what the `Debug.Print` is for.

```
 If row("Criteria").ToString = "Criteria 1" Then
                row("Criteria") = row("Criteria").ToString & $" <p>{CStr(row("Option"))}"
                Debug.Print(row("Criteria").ToString)
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit but I don't think a DataTable has anything to do with html. A grid yes, but the DataTable exists only in memory. What would html.Append do?

Comment: No problem. I can understand the confusion. I was using html as a new StringBuilder.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy Got it! Yes a StringBuilder would be a very good idea in a loop.

Comment: a `StringBuilder` will be helpful(talking about performance) only if there are too many concatenation going on such as , maybe like 10 or more...as per the formatting, formal codes will do and perform the best